# Need help installing MySQL for Python

Tags: python, mysql, adapter, zope

Trying to install [MySQL for Python](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/). Two problems:

1) Instructions over the net says installation is

```
python setup.py
```

For me, it results with

```
can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

2) README.txt says:

```
The Z MySQL database adapter uses the MySQLdb package.
This must be installed before you can use the Z MySQL DA. You can find this at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python
```

Which simply leads to the package itself, not anything else.

Thanks for your help.

PS. I'm using a Mac + Leopard.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing A [`Zope product`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zope) (`ZMySQLDA`) with the [python-mysqldb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) package.
Try one of the [download files](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/), if it doesn't help, go for the [source](http://mysql-python.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mysql-python/trunk/).
Note that the source trunk is clearly divided into `ZMySQLDA/` and `MySQLdb/` .

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Debian based distro you can :

`apt-get install python-mysqldb` ( or aptitude if you prefer ).

Comment: Forgot to mention: Using a Mac. Leopard.

Comment: Looks like there's py-mysql, py26-mysql, py25-mysql on MacPorts @ http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=variant&substr=mysql4