# Error installing mysql-python module on Win7 & Python 2.7

Tags: python, mysql, windows, mysql-python

Whatever I try : downloading the tarball archive of mysql-python and running `python setup.py install`, or using `easy_install mysql-python`, I got the same error which is, (translated from French) : `WindowsError: [Error 2] Can't find the specified file`

The error occurs in the setup_windows.py file, line 7 which is : `serverKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, options['registry_key'])`

If someone has an idea of what's wrong ??? Thanks

---

OK, new element : in the mysql-python source package, there's a site.cfg file that needs to be tuned. 
    # The Windows registry key for MySQL.
    # This has to be set for Windows builds to work.
    # Only change this if you have a different version.
    registry_key = SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.0
My problem is that my dev box doesn't host the MySQL server which runs on another box. Thus, there's no MySQL installation to be found on my PC.

I got some answers from [Installing python-mysql with wamp's mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581431/installing-python-mysql-with-wamps-mysql)

---

OK Up and running. 
Get the clue from http://lyilei.wordpress.com/2011/03/22/install-mysqldb-python/
and ended up grabbing the unofficial binary installer from the given URL : http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

But... this binary package is tied to MySQL 5.1.

Comment: Don't add [SOLVED] to your title. Post your solution as an answer and then accept that. That will show that you have solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

if no need to manually install  then
go to this link and download mysql installer  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score -1):

Right click your python executable and got to properties/computability and set the checkbox to run as administrator.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I thought it would do it but no. I did the same with easy_install.exe, even tweak the .manifest file to claim <requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false"/> but I still get the same error message.